# Measuring uptime of a service with Graphite+Grafana

Tags: performance, apache-spark, graphite, grafana

My question is a bit philosophic: how would you calculate uptime of a process based on it's Graphite metrics?

I have many instances of jvm-process (Apache Spark). Each one reports metrics to Graphite every 5 minutes while it's alive. I want to calculate uptime for each process and average uptime for all of them this week and this month.

For now I had no luck to find suitable method in Graphite or Grafana which computes time of each measurement. Maybe I need to use an external script.
Also would be nice to display average uptime as a single-stat panel in Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this functionality doesn't exist yet. But if your website is in the public network then Pingdom does the job pretty good.